# Как это реализовать?

Tags: html, css, frontend

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Начала заниматься версткой недавно. Попался вот такой макет. Как расположить картинки именно так?

Answer (score 3):

```css
div {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

img {
  width: 30%;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

img:first-child {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500">
</div>
```

```css
div {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

img:first-child {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let img = document.querySelector('.wrapper-img2').querySelectorAll('img');
let wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper-img img')

for(let i = 0; i < img.length; i++){
  img[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
    wrapper.src = img[i].src
    console.clear();
  })
}
```

```css
.wrapper-img, .wrapper-img2{
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  -ms-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: calc(450px + 60px);
  margin: auto;
  height: calc(100px + 60px);
}
.wrapper-img img, .wrapper-img2 img{
  margin: 10px;
  width: calc( 100% - 10px );
  height: calc( 100% - 10px );
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-img">
  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="">
</div>

<div class="wrapper-img2">
  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="">
  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="">
  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

я сам новичек, но мне кажется вам подойдет display: flex; https://tproger.ru/translations/how-css-flexbox-works/